# Linking this html to the database

Tags: php, html, sql

I hope this is what you mean

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.6deb5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Oct 15, 2017 at 12:30 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-1
-- PHP Version: 7.0.22-3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `Taheal`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test`
--

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `item_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Total` int(11) AS (Price*item_num) PERSISTENT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `test`
--
ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `test`
--
ALTER TABLE `test`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

here is the connect1.php with the right credentials given 
and the database named Taheal consists of table named test columns (ID,first_name,Price,last_name,item_num,Total), however it still does nothing when i press submit on the html form

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "Youssef123";
$dbname = "test";

$fname = $_POST['fname']
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$it_num = $_POST['it_num'];

/** Create connection **/
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

/** 
* Use !empty($var) instead of $var, because is fast and return TRUE only if $var not empty 
* Use urlencode() to generate correct $_GET string
**/
if (!empty($conn->connect_error)) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode($conn->connect_error));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}

if( empty($fname) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('fname is empty'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}
if( empty($lname) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('lname is empty'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}

if( empty($it_num) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('it_num is empty'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
} else if( !is_numeric($it_num) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('it_num must be a number'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}

/**
* Example of db_table_field    :    first_name
* SQL                          :    INSERT INTO test ('first_name') ...
* Use mysql_escape_string() to prevent Injection of JS code, etc, into DB
**/
$SQL = "INSERT INTO test ('first_name', 'last_name', 'item_num') VALUES ('".mysql_escape_string($fname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($lname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($it_num)."')";

/** Use === instead of ==, because It's more secure **/
if ($conn->query($SQL) === TRUE ) {
    header('location: /form.php?success='.urlencode('Thank you for inserting info in the database') );
} else {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode($conn->error));
}

exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/

?>
```

and here is the new form.php that i created

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtm111/DTD/xhtm111.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang=en
<html>
<head> <title>Taheal</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor ="lightyellow">
    <?php if(!empty($_GET['success'])) { ?>
    <div class="SUCCESS_MESSAGE">
        <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
    </div>
    <a href="/form.php">New insert</a>
    <?php } else if(!empty($_GET['error'])) { ?>
    <div class="SUCCESS_MESSAGE">
        <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
    </div>
    <a href="/form.php">Retry</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
 <form name="consumables" method ="post" action="connect1.php"/>
 <table border = "2" align = "center" bgcolor = "lightblue">
 <tr>
 <td colspan= "2" align = "center">Form</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><center><font color = "red" >consumables:</font><center>
 <select type = "text" name = "fname" value =""></center>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><center><font color="red" >RoomNum:</font><center>
 <select type="text" name="lname" value=""/></center>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>

 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
        <td><center><font color="red" >ItemNum:</font><center>
        <select type="text" name="it_num" value=""></center>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>


        </select>
        </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value='submit'> </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>

 
 </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

i need help with this code. it should connect to 'connect.php' then appy the code to Insert data in database named 'test' and give feedback to user that his data has been inserted

```html
<?php include('connect.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtm111/DTD/xhtm111.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang=en
<html>
<head> <title>Taheal</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor ="lightyellow">
 <form name="consumables" method ="post" action="connect.php"/>
 <table border = "2" align = "center" bgcolor = "lightblue">
 <tr>
 <td colspan= "2" align = "center">Form</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><center><font color = "red" >consumables:</font><center>
 <select type = "text" name = "fname" value =""></center>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><center><font color = "red" >RoomNum:</font><center>
 <select type="text" name ="lname" value=""/></center>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>

 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
        <td><center><font color = "red" >ItemNum:</font><center>
        <select type = "text" name = "it_num" value =""></center>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>


        </select>
        </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan = "2" align = "center"><input type="submit" name= "submit" value = 'submit'> </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>

 
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the 'connect.php' file

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "test";

$fname = $_POST['fname']
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$it_num = $_POST['it_num'];

//   create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

//   check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (empty($fname)){
 echo "sometxt"
 die();
}

if (empty($lname)){
        echo "sometxt"
        die();
}

if (empty($it_num)){
        echo "sometxt"
        die();
}

$sql ="INSERT INTO test ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$item_num')
VALUES {('$fname')}, {('$lname')}, {('$it_num')}";

if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
 echo  "thank you for inserting info in the database"
} else {
 echo "ERROR: " $sql . "<br>" .$conn->error;

}
$conn->close()
?>
```

i just need to know if the problem is in syntax of what because after i submit the items it does not do anything. just hangs at 'localhost/db/connect.php'.
and does not give error.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all :** You don't need to include "connect.php" in "form.php" file, because You call it when submit form

> Delete: (leftArrow)? php include('connect.php'); ?>

---

### Fix without jQuery library

> ATTENTION : HTML file must have PHP extension (Instead of form.html use form.php)

```
/** PHP File connect.php **/

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "test";

$fname = $_POST['fname']
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$it_num = $_POST['it_num'];

/** Create connection **/
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

/** 
* Use !empty($var) instead of $var, because is fast and return TRUE only if $var not empty 
* Use urlencode() to generate correct $_GET string
**/
if (!empty($conn->connect_error)) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode($conn->connect_error));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}

if( empty($fname) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('fname is empty'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}
if( empty($lname) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('lname is empty'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}

if( empty($it_num) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('it_num is empty'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
} else if( !is_numeric($it_num) ) {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode('it_num must be a number'));
    exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/
}

/**
* Example of db_table_field    :    first_name
* SQL                          :    INSERT INTO test ('first_name') ...
* Use mysql_escape_string() to prevent Injection of JS code, etc, into DB
**/
$SQL = "INSERT INTO test ('db_table_field_1', 'db_table_field_2', 'db_table_field_3') VALUES ('".mysql_escape_string($fname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($lname)."', '".mysql_escape_string($it_num)."')";

/** Use === instead of ==, because It's more secure **/
if ($conn->query($SQL) === TRUE ) {
    header('location: /form.php?success='.urlencode('Thank you for inserting info in the database') );
} else {
    header('location: /form.php?error='.urlencode($conn->error));
}

exit; /** Prevent the script from running in background **/

?>
```

> $conn->close() is not necessary if We exit from PHP script =)

```
/** form.php file **/

<DOCTYPE ...>
...
<body bgcolor ="lightyellow">
    <?php if(!empty($_GET['success'])) { ?>
    <div class="SUCCESS_MESSAGE">
        <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
    </div>
    <a href="/form.php">New insert</a>
    <?php } else if(!empty($_GET['error'])) { ?>
    <div class="SUCCESS_MESSAGE">
        <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
    </div>
    <a href="/form.php">Retry</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <form>
        ... SHOW FORM HTML HERE ...
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

---

### Fix with jQuery library

If You need a more dynamic technique, it's necessary to use jQuery methods (JavaScript)

If You want to try It, I can edit this post =) No problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer i really appreciate it. I want to ask you first about urlencode because i am a begginer here and second thing is the changes you made should make it work if i replace the variables with mine like column names and so on?

Comment: i have tried to modify the variables to match mine and the name to form.php but still it moves to the connect.php and nothing happens no messeges nothing

Comment: @JOE -- Hi Joe, sorry for the late answer. I'll try to answer You as easily as possible

Comment: @JOE -- FIRST QUESTION --

We have a string like this "How many cats there are on the Mom's table?", if We don't use urlencode the PHP script redirect to form.php?error="How many cats there are on the Mom's table" and this is wrong! Because there isn't concatenate symbol, in addition specials symbols are not allowed in get requests (like as ', ", $, ..)

What do we do? Simple, We use urlencode and get automatic translated string for GET\POST request. 

TRY THIS [link](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/)

Comment: @JOE -- SECOND QUESTION -- Yes! You must change db_table_field_1 to Your's db table field

Comment: @JOE -- REPLY TO ERROR -- Can You post your DB table schema? (Ex. name of DB, fields of DB) Are you sure that DB credentials are correct?

Comment: i edited the post to contain more info about the db and also the form.php and connect1.php, i hope the problem seems obvious to you, and not complicated. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JOE Yeah! I understand the problem but I need Your exactly DB Schema. I don't understand if "$first_name" is field or "first_name" is field.... Is $ a field char?

Comment: @JOE Are you sure that the DB is configured? What do You use? (XAMPP with MySQL, IIS with MSSQL, ...) When You click on submit, are you redirect to connect1.php page?

Comment: I am using MySQL on a Kali Linux OS , yes it redirects to connect1.php but shows a blank white page.

Comment: @JOE in connect1.php add these line BEFORE content ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); and retry

Comment: Still give me a blank white page no errors nothing. i dont know what is the problem

Comment: @JOE are you sure that PHP IS configured correctly? Send me an email with all files to pterracciano95@gmail.com